# Hierarchical auto-populated menu

Tags: plugin-system, wildmenu

I'm aware of vim menu and plugins such as `vim-venu` and `quickmenu`, but they need to be manually configured.

Is there a way to populate vim menus with all commands available organized in a hierarchical structure based on (for instance) the installed plugins from which each command derives?

I'm thinking to a way to find commands for which you don't remember the name. Something like spacemacs. You open the menu, see the options (e.g. plugins or integrated), chose one (e.g. plugins), chose a plugin (e.g. FZF), chose a command from that plugin... In all of this you don't have to exactly remember any name, neither the plugin itself, and you can also "discover" some new feature, maybe

Comment: Are you thinking of something like emacs's helm? There are several plugins that offer similar things, but they do require some configuration. Auto-discovering all available commands/mappings is do-able, but messy

Comment: Yep, something which enhance the discoverability of vim commands. Why is it so hard to do automatically?

Comment: I think you would need the complete function, or some other similar mechanism. Is there something wrong with `:` completion? Or are you thinking more of normal mode commands?

Comment: I'm thinking to a way to find commands for which you don't remember the name. Something like spacemacs. You open the menu, see the options (e.g. plugins or integrated), chose one (e.g. plugins), chose a plugin (e.g. FZF), chose a command from that plugin... In all of this you don't have to exactly remember any name, neither the plugin itself, and you can also "discover" some new feature, maybe

Comment: You can also parse `split(execute('verbose command'), "\n")` result. From the path, you can isolate the (highlevel) plugin name -- depending on the plugin manager used, there would be slight differences. It would be more tricky for filetype related commands as they won't always appear.
It'd be better if their plugins were populating themselves the menus from the commands and mappings that we can never remember.

Comment: `:put =execute('verbose command')` Then find the stuff you're interested in and press `K`. Adding a sorting step is doable but require a few lines of code.